# Почему переменная из другого файла не работает в функции второго файла? python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот код, из которой мне нужно достать переменную items.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://sinoptik.com.ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA-101500607/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.1.81 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    global items
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find('div', class_='weather__article_description-text').get_text()
    print(items)
    return items

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Error Sinoptik')
parse()
```

Вот код, куда мне нужно доставить переменную.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from narmon import temp
from sinoptik import *

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = "")
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})

def function(): 
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.to_me:

                    msg = event.text.lower()
                    id = event.user_id

                    if msg == 'погода':
                        sender(id, items + temp)
    except:
        function()
function()
```

Что я делаю не так? Как мне достать переменную items?

Comment: Не очень хорошо делать всё через global, но попробуйте в function написать в начале global items

Comment: @CrazyElf щас проверю

Comment: Но правильнее будет в parse сделать return get_content, а в function сделать items = parse(), т.е. в явном виде вызывать функции и передавать данные

Comment: почему то если я вызываю принт с переменной итемс текст выводится. но если засунуть эту переменную в функцию сендер, то функция как будто отключается. перестает реагировать

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, помог